# How to roll back (reset) a committed change in git on a single file

Tags: git, git-merge, git-rebase, git-reset

I have a commit on my feature branch, consisting of 3 files, one of which now has a merge conflict with master.

I'd like to:

- roll back the commit on the conflicted file
- rebase from master onto the file that had the conflict
- manually reapply my rolled back changes on that file

I've tried reverting but this works on the whole commit not the single file.

I've tried checking out the single file (at its revision prior to the commit I want to roll back) and committing that (to essentially revert the single file). However when I rebase the conflict still happens.

I feel like I need to do a hard reset on this single file somehow but I can't see a way of resetting an individual file.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `git checkout` to [get a single file](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-checkout#git-checkout-emgitcheckoutemlttree-ishgt--ltpathspecgt82308203) from another commit like so:

```
git checkout <commit> -- path/to/file
```

To prevent the conflict, you should squash the new commit into the previous (conflicting) commit.

---

A rebase will apply each commit in the list, one at a time. If you have a conflict, then every single time you rebase you will have to re-address that conflict. That's one reason that I prefer a good ol' merge. Merges happen at the top of the stack (so your anti-conflict commit will apply), and any conflicts you do run into only need to be solved once.

If you really want to use a rebase, then you can `git rebase -i HEAD~N` (where N is however many commits you need to go back to get to the conflicting commit) then edit that commit directly (place an `e` next to it in the editor) or squash the second commit into the first (place an `s` next to the new commit). Basically, you need to change your commit history. Then you should be able to rebase off master.

Comment: I tried that but the rebase afterwards fails: "I've tried checking out the single file (at its revision prior to the commit I want to roll back) and committing that (to essentially revert the single file). However when I rebase the conflict still happens."

Comment: Squashing the two commits together helped!

Answer (score 1):

The problem here is conceptual: you're taking commands that apply to commits, and trying to apply them to files, and this is skewing your reasoning about how to address the problem at hand.

To clarify: files are not committed individually.  Each commit has a single `TREE`, which represents the state of the entire project content.  You change three files, this creates a new state of the content; you `git commit`, this creates *a single new `COMMIT` object* with a `TREE` representing the new state of the project.

Perhaps the confusion comes from familiarity with other source control tools.  The commit model used by `git` is in contrast to CVS, where changes are committed to individual versioned files, for example.

So if you roll back using something like `reset`, you undo *all* of your changes.  If you `rebase` to get changes from `master`, you get *all* of the changes from master.

This doesn't mean you can't get where you want to go; you just have to approach it a bit differently.

The simplest (and IMO most correct for the situation) thing to do is to resolve this during the merge operation.  Once get tells you there are conflicts, you can get `master`s version of the one conflicting file

```
git checkout master -- path/to/conflicting/file
```

Then you can use whatever editor or IDE you're using to manually re-apply your changes.  (You can always `git diff HEAD`git merge-base HEAD master`-- path/to/conflicting/file` if you need to review the changes you originally made.)  Then

```
git add path/to/conflicting/file
```

to mark the conflict as resolved, and

```
git commit
```

to finish the merge.

Comment: You're right. I guess where I said "rebase from master onto the file that had the conflict" really I want to simply "rebase from master". Since while I want the changes from master that are on that single file, it doesn't make much sense to bring that file across from master in isolation. The purpose of wanting to roll back the single file was so that I only had to reapply my changes on that one file, rather than for my entire commit. Still I don't really get how merging is 'better' than rebasing here, since rebasing results in a cleaner history doesn't it?

Comment: OK, I'm understanding a bit more now. The merge preserves history making it easier to roll back/fix issues introduced by the merge/conflict. I think I've become obsessed with a clean history at the expense of losing information.

Comment: @andrea- Sorry, just getting back to this...  Yes, rebase has pros and cons.  Many people find the linear history they can get with frequent rebasing to be pleasing; but it can also create intermediate commits that are broken, and depending on the approach to collaborative development it's possible for other problems to exist.  My answer was geared toward completing the merge because that appeared to be what you asked; a rebase solution is possible, but may take extra conflict resolution steps.

Comment: I actually ended up undoing the rebase and doing a merge to preserve history (I undid the rebase by luckily having a pre-rebase clone on my machine which I could force push to the server). But the other answer still answers my perhaps misguided question more accurately even though this one is closer to what I actually did!